# Creating a new column with a specific value

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this data frame (bonds) to which I want to add a column "helix" with values H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, and H6 that are dependent on the value of the column "Number2" as follows:

```
H1: 789 - 798
H2: 802 - 810
H3: 814 - 824
H4: 828 - 844
H5: 849 - 859
H6: 863 - 873
```

So far I tried

```
bonds$Helix1 <- ifelse(bonds$Number2<=798, "YES", "NO")
```

but this would produce 5 different columns for H1, H2, H3, H4, and H5 with values yes or no, but I want a single column that attributes the values H1, H2, H3, H4, or H5.

I also tried

```
bonds$Helix <- if(bonds$Number2 <= 798) {H1} && if(bonds$Number2>=802 & bonds$Number2<=810) {H2} && if (bonds$Number2>= 814 & bonds$Number2 <=824) {H3} && if(bonds$Number2>=828 & bonds$Number2<=844) {H4} && if (bonds$Number2>=849 & bonds$Number2 <= 859) {H5} && if(bonds$Number2>=863 & bonds$Number2 <=873) {H6}
```

But gets an error message:

> Error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

And it's not creating a new column.

Comment: Use `dplyr::case_when()`. Something like: `bonds$Helix <- case_when(bonds$Number2 <= 798 ~ "H1", bonds$Number2 <= 810 ~ "H2", bonds$Number2 <= 824 ~ "H3", etc)` and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Phil. It worked for a single condition, i.e. `bonds$Helix <- case_when(bonds$Number2 <= 798 ~ "H1")` but it didn't for the whole lot `bonds$Helix <- case_when(bonds$Number2 <= 798 ~ "H1", bonds$Number2 2>=802 ~ "H2", bonds$Number2>=814 ~"H3", bonds$Number2>=828 ~"H4", bonds$Number2>=849  ~ "H5", bonds$Number2>=863 ~"H6")` giving the error unexpected numeric constant in "bonds$Helix <- case_when(bonds$Number2 <= 798 ~ "H1", bonds$Number2 2"

Comment: You typoed with an extra 2.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, it worked!